# Discontinuous Martingales on the interval $[0,T]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Does there exist a Martingale on continuous time $[0,T]$ such that it is discontinuous for every $t \in [0,T]$?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Let $\alpha$ be a random variable with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, we set
\begin{align*}
X_t=\mathbb{1}_{\alpha+\mathbb{Q}}(t).
\end{align*}
$X$ is clearly discontinuous everywhere. However, it is a martingale with respect to
the filtration defined by ${\cal F}_t=\sigma(\alpha)$ for all $t\geq 0$. Indeed, for all $0\leq s\leq t$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X_t\mid {\cal F_s})=\mathbb{1}_{\alpha+\mathbb{Q}}(t)=0=X_s\text{ almost surely.}
\end{align*}

Comment: But we can find a version of $X_t$ which is continuous. Is it possible to find $X_t$ that is "truly" discontinuous?